# MATLAB: datasets stuck in each box

Tags: matlab, file, extract

I'm unsure how to phrase exactly my problem. I have run a script and it is putting each file of data into one box, making four files, a 1x4 array. I can click on each and t will expand, however this is not the format that is acceptable. Is it possible to extract this to turn it into one single file? [I attached a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFIA4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your second file has 23 columns instead of 24, so you cannot just add them together. If you add a column to the second file you can convert them using:

```
b=cell2mat(a')
```

adding a column can be done like this:

```
a{2}(:,24)=nan;
```

Comment: Ah, let me rephrase, I would like to make a file that is about 23 across, but then about 17,000 rows. So I am connecting them. I don't want to physically add the numbers.

Comment: I added the column to make all 24 - however, it gives my cat errors

Comment: Have you tried just using vertcat(A,B) to combine two of those files?

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html